# Why can't I launch Sublime Text 3 with sudo from my command line?

Tags: environment-variables, osx-mavericks

I just installed Sublime Text 3 on OS X Maverick, and it works fine.

I want to launch it from the command line, and I put a symbolic link to it like this:

```
 sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl \
            /usr/local/bin/subl
```

It worked. I can now do

```
$ subl <-- Launches Sublime Text 3 sucessfully
$ which subl
/usr/local/bin/subl

$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

But I can't do this:

```
$ sudo subl
Unable to find Sublime Text
```

I can't figure out why, because:

```
$ sudo which subl
/usr/local/bin/subl

sudo echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Why can't I launch Sublime Text 3 with sudo from my command line?

Comment: What happens with `sudo /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl`?

Comment: @trojanfoe sudo /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl successfully launces Sublime Text 3!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've now told me that:

```
$ sudo /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```

Successfully launches Sublime Text 3, then I would recommend using a shell alias, rather than symlink to make this more convenient.

Edit your `~/.bash_profile` and add:

```
alias subl="/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
alias sudosubl="sudo /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
```